# python selenium having difficulties with click

Tags: python, python-3.x

Currently using python and trying to have selenium click the `"About"` on google without using id. When I try to use `.click()` it does not execute, what is wrong with my code? I have looked at many videos and tutorials and it looks correct.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

browser = webdriver.Safari()
browser.get('http://google.com')
browser.maximize_window()

elm = browser.find_element_by_link_text('About')
browser.implicitly_wait(5)
elm.click()
```

Comment: I assume you mean "currently" and not "currency"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue ended up being safari. For some reason the web driver safari was not allowing me to use `.click`. I switched to chrome and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can try using `find_element_by_xpath`.
First you will copy xpath of `about` link then you can try like below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

browser =  webdriver.Safari()
browser.get('http://google.com')
browser.maximize_window()

elm = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="fsl"]/a[3]')
browser.implicitly_wait(5)
elm.click()
```

Comment: When you run that does it work? Its not working for me. I have tried everything from find_element_by_xpath find_element_by_id and ind_element_by_name.

Comment: yeah it's working for me. xpath can be different for you. first you copy your about link xpath then paste into  `find_element_by_xpath()`. I think, it will work!